# Python tkinter button returns to black while pressed

Tags: python, button, tkinter, colors

I'm using Tkinter and I've noticed that  my buttons become black while mouse button is held down irrespective of what color I have stated when declaring the button.

Does anyone know if this can be controlled?

Kind regards,¨

Daniel

Comment: Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the `activebackground` and `activeforeground` properties.
Read more about them [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm).